# Jquery .html wont load the css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Says, i write this code :

```
<div class="modal fade" id="addnewevent">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
<button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
<h4 class="modal-title">
New Event
</h4>
</div>
<div class="modal-body">
<form name="newevent" id="newevent" action="" method="post">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="eName">Title</label>
<input name="eName" id="eName" class="form-control" type="text">
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="eDate">Date</label>
<div class="input-group date datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
<input name="eDate" id="eDate" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=date("d-m-Y",$now)?>"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></input>
</div>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="eLevel">Event Level</label>
<select name="eLevel" id="eLevel" class="select2able" >
<option value=""></option>
<option value="1">Normal</option>
<option value="2">Urgent</option>
</select>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="eDesc">Deskripsi</label>
<textarea name="eDesc" id="eDesc" class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="150"></textarea>
</div>
</form>
</div>
<div class="modal-footer">
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="add" type="button">Add</button><button class="btn btn-default-outline" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">close</button>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

This will gave me result like this picture : 
http://imageshack.com/a/img542/7466/okj7.png

Then, i use :

```
    function change(id) {

    $.post('ajax/change.php', {
        data: id,
        rand: Math.random()
    },
    function (html) {
        $('#changeform').html(html);
        $("#modalchange").modal('show');
    });

}
```

triggered from this button :

```
<a class="table-actions" href="#" onClick="change('<?=$tm['id']?>');return false;"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></a>
```

The code for html (from change.php) is like this :

```
<?php

    if(isset($_POST['data'])) {

        $id     = $_POST['data'];
        $evt    = mysql_query("select * from cal_event where id = '$id'");
        $evt    = mysql_fetch_array($evt);
        $dt     = explode(",",$evt['date']);

    ?>

        <input type="hidden" value="<?=$id?>" name="uid" />
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eName">Title</label>
            <input name="eName" id="eName" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$evt['title']?>">
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eDate">Date</label>
            <div class="input-group date datepicker" data-date-autoclose="true" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <input name="eDate" id="eDate" class="form-control" type="text" value="<?=$dt[2]."-".($dt[1]+1)."-".$dt[0]?>"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="icon-calendar"></i></span></input>
            </div>                  
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eLevel">Event Level</label>
            <select name="eLevel" id="eLevel" class="select2able" >
                <option value=""></option>
                <option <?=($evt['level']==1)?"selected":""?> value="1">Normal</option>
                <option <?=($evt['level']==2)?"selected":""?> value="2">Urgent</option>
            </select>   
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label for="eDesc">Deskripsi</label>
            <textarea name="eDesc" id="eDesc" class="form-control" rows="3" maxlength="150"><?=$evt['deskripsi']?></textarea>
        </div>

    <?php

    }

?>
```

this is modal change

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modalchange">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button aria-hidden="true" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Change Event</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body" >
            <form name="changeform" id="changeform" action="" method="post">
            </form>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" id="change" type="button">Change</button><button class="btn btn-default-outline" data-dismiss="modal" type="button">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but the result is different, it's give me like this :
http://imageshack.com/a/img89/3892/tpo5.png

So, how can i solve this problem?
and sorry for my bad in english.

Comment: What language are you using to generate the html?

Comment: where is your  `#changeform`?

Comment: Looks like a plugin, but which one???

Comment: what is inside your `html` that you wanna insert in `#changeform` ? by using 'html' you change your html inside `form tag`,but what about `style`? how you apply to you `form`?

Answer (score 1):

From the picture you posted, the `select` element should not be just styled with css, there should be some javascript magic (which transform the select element to something else and hide the select element).

So you have to apply the javascript to the new html content again.

Comment: yes, it's like that when i looked up at the view source on the browser. class select2able loaded more class if i looked on the view source